# How to send Object by Post request using native Ajax on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ajax

I am trying to POST the input filed value as an object to the NodeJs controller. Here i am using native ajax POST method. And body-parser package on nodejs to access the POST request. But when i log the res.body i see its empty. I am new in Ajax and NodeJs. Sorry if i am making any obvious mistakes...

```
window.addEventListener("load" , () => {
let formSubmit = document.querySelector("#formSubmit");
formSubmit.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inputTodo = document.querySelector("#inputTodo").value;
    let todo = {item : inputTodo};
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST" , "/todo" ,  true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    let data = todo;
    console.log(data)
    xhr.send(data);
    location.reload();
})
```

});

```
app.post("/todo" ,urlencodedParser,  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    data.push(req.body);
    res.json(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the method in template engine form as POST solved the problem for me. It's a GET method by default but somehow when we are using the jQuery Ajax we don't need to change the method. And it works fine. But if we want to use Native Ajax we must set the POST method in the form  even when we are defining the type as POST.

```
form(
    method="POST"
    action="/Contact"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are sending and undefined data object, for what i see in your code you never assign any value to the data variable before call the .send(data) method. So try with this and should work

```
xhr.send({id: 'example_id'});
```

Comment: That also don't work. When i console log i can see the object stored in data. But after sending it to server when i console log it from server i see it's empty. I edited the code that i tried. Please check it again.